# Property of the matrix for Kirchhoff equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When solving problems of linear electrical circuits by the method of Kirchhoff equations or the like, we obtain a matrix of a system of linear equations.

The resulting solution must satisfy the nonlinear energy conservation law.

What are the purely mathematical properties of such matrices that ensure the fulfillment of the nonlinear law of conservation of energy? It is not the physical meaning that interests, but the mathematical properties.

P.S. Sorry Google for the quality of its translation :)

P.P.S. Simplest circuit to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the "nonlinear energy conservation law" that you're referring to?

Comment: @BenGrossmann The solution gives the values of the currents in the branches. The law of conservation of energy consists in the equality of the sums I^2\*R and sums I\*E over all branches of the electric circuit. Perhaps, for understanding, I should give a solution to some simple problem?

Comment: I think that could be helpful here

Comment: From quick reading, it seems that Kirchhoff's circuit laws are derived from [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) rather than simply being the consequences of conservation of energy

Comment: @BenGrossmann Small solution is added. Maxwell's equations have nothing to do with it. We are talking about the law of line current (current = voltage / resistance, U = R\*I), and the law of conservation of charge. It is admirable that a set of linear equations always results in some quadratic form having an exact value. Why?

Comment: Conservation of charge is a consequence of Maxwell's equations (specifically Ampere's law for static electric fields). $U = R*I$ doesn't give you Kirchhoff's voltage law; Kirchhoff's voltage law is a consequence of the Maxwell-Faraday equation, [as is explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law).

Comment: In other words, it is true that the equations at play satisfy a conservation law, but the conservation of energy is not enough in and of itself to derive the equations of interest. Perhaps this is besides the point, but I this is what I thought you were getting at before.

Comment: If we frame things in terms of Maxwell's equations and the associated Lagrangian, then the fact that there is an associated conservation of energy can be seen as an instance of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Alas, my knowledge of English is not enough to convey the very essence of the question. It’s not physics, but mathematics (I myself am a radiophysicist). Unfortunately, I do not know in which area of mathematics to look for the answer to my question. The question is more philosophical, and certainly not physical. I understand physics, I am interested in the mathematical properties of the matrix. In a word, the question must be closed, simply because I cannot ask it correctly.

Comment: I don't know if it must be closed per se. It might help if you posted an explanation in your native language so that the users of this site could attempt to translate it for themselves. Based on our discussion so far, I think that Noether's theorem comes the closest to addressing your question. In general, it describes how conservation laws emerge "naturally" from the constraints that define a system. In this case, one of the symmetries over the action corresponding to the Lagrangian governing Kirchhoff's laws must correspond to the conservation of energy.

Comment: This is a great question. You're asking what special properties of the matrices that arise in circuit equations guarantee that energy is conserved. I have no idea, but it does remind me vaguely of matrices that describe Markov chains which preserve the sum so that total probability is always 1, and that can be understood in terms of the matrix having a uniform left eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. But in that case the conservation is linear...

Comment: It could also be related to eigenvectors in this case - maybe they consevation can somehow be related to seeing the matrix as a quadratic form, and then an eigenvalues of 1 could play a role...